# Calling a class function without triggering the __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Is there any way to call functions inside a class without triggering the `__init__` part of that class? Let's say I have the next class, usually I'd call the function this way:

```
class Potato():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Initializing")
    def myfunction(self):
        print("I do something")

Potato().myfunction()
```

But as expected that prints the Initializing part. Now, If I wanted to call myfunction without triggering that. How would you do it? Pros and cons of doing it? It's even possible?

Comment: What... Then just don't use `__init__`. You're not initializing any variables in that example anyways.

Comment: that was just an example,I want to know what would happen if the real code would have variables in there but I didn't want to call them when calling functions. Or if it's even possible.

Comment: You don't "call" variables. `__init__` "initializes". Meaning as soon as you instantiate a class, that particular instance gets whatever variables you initialized as a property. I don't know what you mean by "not calling them when calling functions".

Comment: Sorry for confussion, english is no my main language. I just wanted to know if there is a way to exclude the `__init__` function of a class when you instance a class. Hope that makes more sense. @Trauer probably, I am learning classes and how they work, and I stumbled upon this. I know there is better ways to call functions but I just wanted to adress my curiosity of "it's possible to do this...?".

Comment: You can create a subclass that overrides the `__init__` method to do nothing... not sure what the point would be, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

#### Using a helper function

You could write a helper function that replace `__init__` method of your class with a dummy method and then instantiates the class and after this we re-assign the old `__init__` back to class.

```
def skip_init(cls):
    actual_init = cls.__init__
    cls.__init__ = lambda *args, **kwargs: None
    instance = cls()
    cls.__init__ = actual_init
    return instance
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> a = skip_init(Potato)
>>> a.myfunction()
I do something
```

---

#### Overriding `__new__`

You could override `__new__` method of your class and there based on argument you can replace `__init__` with a dummy method.

```
def new_init(cls, init):
    def reset_init(*args, **kwargs):
        cls.__init__ = init
    return reset_init


class Potato():
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = object.__new__(cls)
        lazy = kwargs.pop('_no_init', False)
        if not lazy:
            return instance
        cls.__init__ = new_init(cls, cls.__init__)
        return instance

    def __init__(self):
        print("Initializing")

    def myfunction(self):
        print("I do something")
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> a  = Potato(_no_init=True)
>>> a.myfunction()
I do something
>>> b  = Potato()
Initializing
>>> b.myfunction()
I do something
```

Comment: That's what I needed to know, if it was possible at all. Thank you.

Comment: @Saelyth Glad that helped. Added another way that you may find useful.

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 19):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but:

A classmethod or a staticmethod could be used without creating an instance of the class - which means that **init** would not be called that way:

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self):
      print("Initialize instance - not used")

   @staticmethod
   def my_static(toprint):
       print(toprint)

MyClass.my_static("Print this")
```

Comment: That might be, care to explain a bit?

Comment: I added an example to demonstrate use of a static method

Comment: This is the path I would take. I don't know why you would use the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh that was a newbie fail: I actually made 2 answers. The first one was if it was even possible to not initialize the `__init__` so I accepted the answer because I had to know the capabilities of classes on that matter and that got covered pretty well. Then the alternative question would had been how to call methods inside classes without initializing it, and in that matter I agree this is nice to know.

Comment: 2 questions, not answers. Wow, I was that stupid yesterday...?

Answer (score 2):

I know this was posted a while ago, but worth mentioning that a class method without "self" can be invoked without calling the constructor with () and with no init. Not really adding anything new but I think it answers the question simply.

```py
>>> class Yolo:
...     def notify(data):
...         print(f"some data: {data}")
...
>>>
>>> Yolo.notify({1:1})
some data: {1: 1}
>>>
```

and

```
>>> class Yolo:
...     @staticmethod
...     def notify(data):
...         print(f"some data: {data}")
...
>>> Yolo.notify({1:1})
some data: {1: 1}
```

Compared with

```
>>> class Yolo:
...    def __init__(self):
...       print("init")
...    def notify(data):
...       print(f"some data: {data}")
...
>>>
>>> Yolo.notify({1:1})
some data: {1:1}
>>> Yolo()
init
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can create a class without an **init** but it's going to behave more like a function.

2) If you use the `__init__` method, then it's going to be called everytime the class is called, but you can avoid it triggering variables if you so chose. Note the method will still get called.

```
class Potato():
    def __init__(self,init_or_dont=1):
        self.init_or_dont = init_or_dont
        if self.init_or_dont:
            print("Initializing")
    def myfunction(self):
        print("I do something")


Potato(init_or_dont=0).myfunction()
```